# Streamwriter position seek

Tags: c#, .net, stream, position, streamwriter

I'm trying to write to a text file the following data:

```
 TEXTed       00:01:27    8.0 xxxxxxx         Some test
 TEXTed       00:01:35  251.0 xxxxxxx         Some text
```

I'm using streamwriter, first building my string and then writing to file:

```
                var v15timeString = item.Duration;
                var v15fileString = "             " + item.Time + "       ";
                v15SR.Write(v15fileString);
                var durLength = item.Duration.Length;
                v15SR.BaseStream.Position = -durLength;
                v15SR.WriteLine(item.Duration);
```

The problem I'm having is for 8.0, 251.0 How do write off these. I want to maintain the .0 for this in all the lines. In layman terms this column should be right aligned. I'm refering this to as item.duration in my code as above.

I did an attempt as above by doing a `streamreader.BaseStream.Position = -durLength`, but the .Position doesn't take a negative number. How can I seek back after `v15filestring`, based on durLength, and then write out the `item.Duration`

Keeping in mind I need to strictly maintain this column as left aligned in the text file as shown in my sample above.

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you need to read about `String.Format` and all width options provided in formatting specifiers... Trying to update position of inner stream of `TextWriter` may not work correctly if writer does not flush content AND it is major pain to compute correct offset in bytes for utf8 strings.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: String.format, is the way to go in my case. please post this as an answer so I may accept it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the random spaces

for example

```
var v15fileString = item.Time.ToString().PadLeft(21);
//and
v15SR.WriteLine(item.Duration.ToString().PadLeft(8));
```

Note: As Ian, has stated, it would be better to build the string up first, then write the line

Comment: I can't padleft to item.duration, because the length always varies. If I pad 8 always it would not be aligned properly.

Comment: @user726720 -  the 8 is an arbitrary number, it will make the total width 8 characters long regardless of length (as long as length <= to this number)

Answer (score 0):

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) lets you specify field width along with other many options. Approximate code would be:

```
 writer.Write(String.Format("{0,10} "{1, 15}", field1, field2));
```

Excerpt from MSDN article:

> The general syntax of a format item is:

```
{index[,alignment][: formatString]}
```

> where alignment is a signed integer that defines the field width. If this value is negative, text in the field is left-aligned. If it is positive, text is right-aligned.

Note: Trying to update position of inner stream of `TextWriter` may not work correctly if writer does not flush content. It is major pain to compute correct offset in bytes for utf8 strings (which is default encoding for .Net test writers).